# Is it possible to use a function/language construct like list to concat to a str variable?

Tags: php, string, variables, variable-assignment

Is there a more elegant way to concat multiple variables as opposed to the 'procedural' method in PHP?

For example lets consider this situation:

```
$sql_columns = $sql_values = '';
foreach ($this->_data as $column => $value)
{
    // How i d like to do it
    // list ($sql_columns, $sql_values) .= array(", $column", ', ?'); #Error

    // procedural method
    $sql_columns .= ", $column";
    $sql_values  .= ', ?';
}
```

Comment: This is the same thing as the "procedural" version stuffed into one line for the heck of it. If you just want to save linebreaks, you can do `$sql_columns .= ", $column"; $sql_values .= ', ?';`. But consider that neither this nor what you propose would be too readable. The only thing that one *may* be able to improve about this code is doing away with the explicit loop altogether.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
$sql_columns = implode(', ', array_keys($this->_data));
$sql_values = rtrim(str_repeat('?, ', count($this->_data)), ', ');
```

Comment: Doesn't the trim kill the string?

Comment: @hakre: Copy and past mistake ;)

Comment: maybe `substr(,0,-2);` :) - i like the string idea.

Comment: @hakre: Yes I thought about that too... might be more efficient. There are several ways :)

Comment: Yea, as ususal, and it's always nice to see some alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

You can operate with arrays, their keys and values. [`implode` <sup>**PHP Manual**</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) is helpful to concatenate values. [`array_fill` <sup>**PHP Manual**</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php) can generate your questions marks. Some quickly typed code:

```
$columns = array_keys($this->_data);
$sql_columns = implode(', ', $columns);
$sql_values = implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($columns), '?'));
```

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.join.php

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
$sql_columns = implode(', ', array_keys($this->_data));
```